# Как выбрать определенные элементы по классу CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Дано:

```
<div class='name1'>
    <div class='name'>1</div>
    <div class='name'>2</div>
</div>

<div class='name2'>div</div>
    <div class='name'>1</div>
    <div class='name'>2</div>
    <div class='name666'>1</div>
    <div class='nam665e'>2</div>
</div>
```

Как можно прописать стили `.name {font-size: 12px;}` для `<div class='name'>`, которые входят только в `<div class='name2'>`? Если в целом для `<div class='name'>` задан стиль, например: `.name {font-size: 18px;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать следующим образом:

```
.name2 div {
   font-size: 12px;
}
```

В данном случае будут выбраны только те `div'ы`, которые находиться внутри блока с именем класса `name2`.

---

Если Вы хотит выбрать только те `div'ы` которые являются прямыми наследниками блока с именем класса `name2`, то:

```
.name2 > div {
   font-size: 12px;
}
```

---

Дополняю ответ в связи с изменением оригинального  вопроса:

```
.name {
   font-size: 18px;
}

.name2 .name {
   font-size: 12px;
}
```

Здесь все аналогично примерам выше.

Справочник [CSS Селекторы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B)

Comment: изменил вопрос, внутри класса .name2 есть еще классы помимо .name. Как быть в таком случае?

Comment: что-то не получилось, у меня в целом прописано для `<div class='name'>` стиль `.name {font-size: 18px;}`, но именно для `<div class='name2'>` у `<div class='name'>` мне нужно сделать `.name {font-size: 12px;}`